# Which one is correct? : "He is descended from Lucrezia Borgia" or "He descends from Lucrezia Borgia"

Tags: verbs

I understand that **Is descended from** is  better than just **descends from**.
Maybe both forms are correct, Please explain.

Comment: The most idiomatic wording (in U.S. English, anyway) is probably "He is a descendant of Lucrezia Borgia." But why one form turns out to be more popular than others may not be explicable.

Comment: To me, *descends from* is somewhat ambiguous. It could also be taken to mean *he lowered himself down from Lucrezia Borgia, on top of whom he'd been perched*. I know that's not the intended meaning in this context, but the same construction could be used if it were.