# descend from vs be descended from

Tags: verbs, passive-voice, past-participles, kinship-terms

Merriam-Webster gives two examples on the usage of "descend from" vs "be descended from" in https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/descend%20from .

---

1. The plants descend from a common ancestor.
2. They claim to be descended from a noble British family.

---

### Question:

Could these two sentences also be rewritten as follows?
What precisely makes the differences of descend from vs be descended from?

a. The plants are descended from a common ancestor.

b. They claim to descend from a noble British family.

---

There is a previous related discussion [Which one is correct? : "He is descended from Lucrezia Borgia" or "He descends from Lucrezia Borgia"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/489113/64032) but there is no definite answer or opinion, concluded from that interesting post.

Comment: Rather like _comprise_.

Comment: How does the passive work here? Maybe I descend, or I descended, but *am descended*?

Comment: I would go with the noun: He is a descendant of Lucretia Borgia. I don't think plants can be descended from; they just descend from, just like people.

Comment: Interesting. Oxford Dictionaries gives as one definition of _descend_ **be a blood relative of (a specified ancestor)**, but the only example supplied is in the passive: **"John Dalrymple was descended from an ancient Ayrshire family"**.  Cambridge treats _descend from_ similarly.

Comment: While I couldn't call 'He descends from a long line of farmers' ungrammatical, 'He is descended from a long line of farmers' sounds far more natural to my ('BrE') ears.

Comment: This issue may have arisen because intransitive verbs are usually not used in past participle form as complements of "to be". Some exceptions are several verbs that indicate condition or change in condition. This used to be much more common in English, but now only certain verbs can be used in this way, including "gone", "retired", "grown", and, of course, "descended".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those are all okay. The difference is that *descended* is functioning as a subject complement / participle adjective, while *descend* is an intransitive verb here. (Either way, there is no passive voice construction possible.)

[*The Oxford Enlish Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required) does not go so far as to label *descended* as an adjective in this usage, but it does **note** that it acts like one:

> **descend**, *v.*
> **a.** *intransitive* (in the perfect). ***to be descended (from, †of)***: to come or derive from a particular progenitor, ancestor, or
> ancestral stock; to be a descendant of.
>  <sub>**Originally the
> perfect tense formed with *be*, but now felt to be a predicative use
> of the past participle with *be*.**</sub>
> <sub>[selected
> examples]</sub>
>  <sub>1944    W. S. Maugham *Razor's Edge* iii. 116
>   I am descended in the female line from the Count de Lauria who
> came over to England in the suite of Philip the Second.</sub>
> <sub>2004    *Focus* Feb. 44/2    Every human on the planet is
> descended from between one and seven women who were part of a group of
> perhaps 200 individuals a few million years ago.</sub>

[Collins goes right ahead and calls it an adjective](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/descended):

> **descended**
>  <sub>ADJECTIVE [v-link ADJ from n]</sub>
>  A person who is descended from someone who lived a long time ago is
> directly related to them.
>  <sub>*Anna is descended from pioneers
> who settled in Colorado in 1898.*</sub>